# select objectfrom routeParam in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a basic cms type of app in angular. I was able to navigate to pages without deep linking like so:

```
 <li ng-repeat="page in pages"><a href="#" ng-click="select(page)">{{page.linktext}}</a></li>
```

with the controller having:

```
$scope.select = function(selected){
    $scope.currentPage = selected;
};
```

No that I am using deep linking I have:

```
<li ng-repeat="page in pages"><a href="#/pages/{{page.linktext}}">{{page.linktext}}</a></li>
```

there is a route provider picking up the pageId

and the controller uses

```
$scope.currentPage = $routeParams.pageId;
```

I realize that the issue is that I am setting currentPage to the id and not the object. How do I select the object with that pageId?

I have added a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/cLNmS/

Comment: What object do you want? To yo want the object to you manually create in your $scope.pages or do you want the route object used by $routeProvider (or are these actually the same object?) Maybe post some more code.

Comment: I want the page that has the pageId passed to routeParams.

Comment: What is "the page" where do you define it?

Comment: I ahve edited my question and include a jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.currentPage = $scope.pages.filter(function (d) { 
     return d.linktext === $routeParams.pageId; 
})[0];
```

Then check `$scope.currentPage` for `undefined`-ness to be sure that a legal URL was passed.

Comment: Thanks, It seems to always return undefined. What is "d" in this example?

Comment: [`filter` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) takes a callback (the anonymous function with argument `d` here) which is called for each element of the array. Assuming `$scope.pages` is an array, then `d` would iteratively take the value of each `page` and return the `page` where `page.linktext === $routeParams.pageId`. Then, assuming that there is only one such `page`, we select the first item from the returned list.

Comment: I have edited my question to include a jsfiddle link. I have your answer added to it but cant get it working.

Comment: Also I think pages might be regarded as an object not an array. In the console, referencing window.myscope = $scope in the controller I was able to get this working: for (var i = 0; i<myscope.pages.length; i++){
if (myscope.pages[i].linktext == "thirdx"){myscope.currentPage = myscope.pages[i]}
}
console.log(myscope.currentPage) but when trying to add to the controller, and changing myscope to $scope it returned 0 because I think .length didnt work in that context.

Comment: @user1469779 The fiddle fails with `Uncaught ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined`.

Comment: The html had the scripts, but jsfiddle told me to use the the external resources panel instead. I was using http://angularfire.com/ as a backend. the scripts were: https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js
https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.3.0/angularfire.min.js